# Access price variable in product object

Tags: product, price, configurable-product

How do I access the price in one of the simple products? The following is the beginning of the array I want to access from my var_dump($_product->debug()); (stackoverflow wouldn't let me post the whole thing). I am working on the issue related to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703427/magento-retrieve-simple-product-price-for-configurable-product

```
["_cache_instance_products"]=>
  array(9) {
    ["0 (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)"]=>
    array(33) {
      ["entity_id"]=>
      string(2) "69"
      ["entity_type_id"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["attribute_set_id"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ["type_id"]=>
      string(6) "simple"
      ["sku"]=>
      string(13) "1001-blu-ven1"
      ["has_options"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["required_options"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(19) "2013-04-02 22:12:27"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(19) "2013-04-02 23:54:41"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(2) "78"
      ["color"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["vendor"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ["name"]=>
      string(14) "test_1 blue v1"
      ["url_key"]=>
      string(14) "test-1-blue-v1"
      ["msrp_enabled"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["msrp_display_actual_price_type"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["image"]=>
      string(12) "no_selection"
      ["small_image"]=>
      string(12) "no_selection"
      ["thumbnail"]=>
      string(12) "no_selection"
      ["options_container"]=>
      string(10) "container2"
      ["url_path"]=>
      string(19) "test-1-blue-v1.html"
      ["weight"]=>
      string(6) "0.0000"
      ["price"]=>
      string(6) "1.0000"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["visibility"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["enable_googlecheckout"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["tax_class_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["is_recurring"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["description"]=>
      string(19) "test_1 blue v1 desc"
      ["short_description"]=>
      string(19) "test_1 blue v1 desc"
```

Comment: So `$_product->getPrice()` and `$_product->getFinalPrice()` are not doing what you need?

Comment: Nope, thats config product price. I need simple product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `getData` output above, it's there, with a $1.00 price:

```
["price"]=>
      string(6) "1.0000"
```

To access, use `$_product->getPrice()`

**Edit:**

While I don't quite follow, hopefully this helps - to get all simples of a configurable parent product, use the following:

```
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                    ->getUsedProducts(null,$_product);   
foreach($childProducts as $child) {
    print_r($child->getPrice());
}
```

In your case it looks as though $_product may contain this simple collection, in which case it may be poorly named. If *that* is that case, I suggest iterating with a foreach:

```
foreach($_product as $_child){
  print_r($_child->getPrice());
}
```

Comment: No that gets the configurable product price. I need the associated simple product price. :)

Comment: Are you sure? Your getData shows `["type_id"]=>
      string(6) "simple"`

Comment: I only posted a fraction of the data that was dumped. Stackexchange won't let me post the whole thing LOL.

Comment: That top part "["_cache_instance_products"]=>" is where it starts to dump the simple products that are associated with the config

Comment: See my edit - I don't know if we're on the right track.  If this doesn't help, perhaps you can paste your debug into a pastie.

Comment: For my own education, how do you find out about the " ->getUsedProducts" method? Is there any way to dump associated methods?

Comment: My clue was in the debug dump -   `array(9) {
    ["0 (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)"]=>` - that told me that the object you were inspecting ($_product) had 9 simple product children. Knowing that, it was simple to demonstrate how to get all children products based on prior knowledge. You could always turn it up with a google search or by searching here - there's some great information available about working with configurables out there.

Comment: It doesn't say used products anywhere though! Is there a secret list of methods somewhere!? LOL. Or do I just have to post in forums and/or search forums every time?